How to display a pdf page into a Flet container
I'm trying to develop a simple app for displaying each page of a Pdf file. I start by adding a container and a button. The Pdf file's full path(absolute path + file name) is given to the variable fullname. The file is converted into a list of PIL images using the pdf2image library.
I'm trying to set the first image(first element of the list) as the content of the container after a button is clicked.
Here is the code:
import flet as ft
import pdf2image


def main(page: ft.Page):
    fullname = r'Your Full Path To the Doc.pdf'
    viewer = pdf2image.convert_from_path(fullname)

    def btn_Click(e):
        cont.content = ft.Image(src = viewer[0],
            fit=ft.ImageFit.FILL,
            )
        page.update()


    cont = ft.Container(height = 0.4*page.height,
        width = 0.4 * page.width,
        border=ft.border.all(3, ft.colors.RED),)

    btn = ft.IconButton(
        icon=ft.icons.UPLOAD_FILE,
        on_click=btn_Click,
        icon_size=35,)    


    page.add(ft.Column([cont, btn], 
        horizontal_alignment="center"))
    page.window_maximized = True
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"
    page.scroll = ft.ScrollMode.AUTO
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")

Why is nothing is displayed in the container and no error shown?

try using syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package and test .
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer

I moddify code to use base64 image src with flet i don't not why, but flet working bad with normal image src and use src_base64 is better choise.
import flet as ft
import pdf2image
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as image
import numpy as np
import base64

import pypdf

i = 0


def main(page: ft.Page):
    fullname = r'D:\BDOT_2015.pdf'
    src_pdf = pypdf.PdfReader(fullname)


    def btn_Click(e):
        global i

        if i >= len(src_pdf.pages):
            i = 0


        out = pypdf.PdfWriter()
        out.add_page(src_pdf.pages[i])
        out.write('t.pdf')

        viewer = pdf2image.convert_from_path('t.pdf',
                                             poppler_path=r'D:\Python\PDF-ORGANIZER\PDF2TIFF\poppler-24.02.0\Library\bin')
        viewer64 = []
        for view in viewer:
            arr = np.asarray(view)
            pil_img = image.fromarray(arr)
            buff = BytesIO()
            pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
            pic = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
            viewer64.append(pic)

        cont.content = ft.Image(src_base64=viewer64[0],
            fit=ft.ImageFit.FILL,
            )
        page.update()


    cont = ft.Container(expand=1,
        border=ft.border.all(3, ft.colors.RED),)

    btn = ft.IconButton(
        icon=ft.icons.UPLOAD_FILE,
        on_click=lambda e: btn_Click(e),
        icon_size=35,)

    def btn_Next(e):
        global i
        i += 1
        btn_Click(e)

    btn_n = ft.IconButton(
        icon=ft.icons.NAVIGATE_NEXT,
        on_click=lambda e: btn_Next(e),
        icon_size=35,)


    page.add(ft.Column([cont, btn, btn_n],
        horizontal_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER))
    page.window_maximized = True
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.scroll = ft.ScrollMode.AUTO
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")

Now your code working as i think you expect.


The solution works fine considering PDF files of a small number of pages. With a PDF file of 155 pages it takes more than 60 seconds to show the first page. Do you know other libraries / methods for PDF view in Flet?

I edited code in answer with still use pdf2image but now with pypdf where i save current page to temporary file and open this little file and when you switch page temporary file is shith to another page etc. It work way faster

Concurrent use of two libraries for pdf page displaying confuses me. The use of pdf2image needs the conversion you specified in your first answer represented by the cycle for. Unfortunately, this is not applicable to pdf documents of many pages.
Reading the pdf with pypdf is for sure more efficient. But displaying each page of the variable 'src_pdf' into the container remains a problem. If I use src instead of src_base64 nothing occurs as before.

Using src_base64 instead, gives me the error displayed into the container and not in the CLI: "Error decoding base64: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1)
{'/Type': '/Page', '/BleedBox': [0, 0, 504, 661.5], '/Contents': IndirectOb..."
